# Microsoft Graph - PowerShell error returning group membership with Get-MgUserMemberOf

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I hope you're well and wish you a happy and healthy new year. I'm updating some PowerShell scripts from Msol/AzureAD to Graph since I understand the former will be deprecated soon. I have one that assigns 365 licenses depending on (A)AD group membership but am getting errors. The relevant part of the script follows:

```
$UnlicensedUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter 'assignedLicenses/$count eq 0' -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable unlicensedUserCount -All | Select Id
ForEach ($User in $UnlicensedUsers)
{
    $Groups = Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserID $User
    if ($Groups -match $NoLicence)
    {
    } elseif ($Groups -match $A3Staff) {
        if ($Groups -match $GroupA) {
            Update-MgUser -UserId $User -UsageLocation GB
            Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $User -AddLicenses $StaffA3SKU -LicenseOptions $StaffA3Options
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Get-MgUserMemberOf : Resource 'Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphUser' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserID $User
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ UserId = Micr...ndProperty =  }:<>f__AnonymousType5`10) [Get-MgUserMemberOf_List], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Request_ResourceNotFound,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgUserMemberOf_List
```

I'm connected to graph with: **Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All, Directory.Read.All**

What I'm trying to do is Get-MgUser to return unlincesed users, then Get-MgUserMemberOf to return all group memberships foreach. I then check for various groups, defined earlier, and assign different license/options on that. I've added Directory.Read.All permission to the app, imported Microsoft.Graph.Users module. I don't know where I'm tripping up. I think the object being returned by Get-MgUser might not be right. Any advice most gratefully received with my thanks in advance.

PS. I notice that Get-MgUser with -Property Id returns: @{Id=} instead of just .

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All, Directory.Read.All

Updated/Consented to app permissions

Comment: I guess you need `Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserID $User.UserPrincipalName` or `Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserID $User.Id`

Comment: Thank you very much @Theo, that turned out to be just the pointer to the solution. I've got it working with the following:

Answer (score 0):

Graph does things quite differently but I was able to crack the changes with the below:

```
$StaffSKU = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where SkuPartNumber -eq '<SKUName>'
$StaffOptions = $StaffSKU.ServicePlans | where ServicePlanName -in ("DisabledPlan1","DisabledPlan2") | Select -ExpandProperty ServicePlanId

$UnlicensedUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter 'assignedLicenses/$count eq 0' -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable unlicensedUserCount -All
ForEach ($User in $UnlicensedUsers)
{
    $Groups = Get-MgUserMemberOf -UserID $User.Id
    if ($Groups.Id -match $NoLicence)
    {
    } elseif ($Groups.Id -match $Staff) {
        if ($Groups.Id -match $GroupA) {
            $AddLicenses = @(
                @{SkuId = $StaffSKU.SkuId
                DisabledPlans = $StaffOptions
                }
            )
            Update-MgUser -UserId $User.Id -UsageLocation GB
            Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $User.Id -AddLicenses $AddLicenses -RemoveLicenses @()
}
```

With Graph API calls, you have to return the SKU object, one cannot just address it by name, or even ID. Despite Get-MgUser returning a user object, Get-MgUserMemberOf needs **just** the user objectid, as does Update-MgUser and Set-MgUserLicense.